# webRequest.GetResponse() throws ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, .net, threadabortexception

I'm running a sync job which syncs data to an api and I'm getting ThreadAbortException a couple of times per day and I cannot figure out why. Code looks like this.

```
var result = new TResult();

        try
        {
            using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream == null)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }

                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        result.HandleResponse(response, content);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var responseStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream == null)
                {
                    result.HandleError(ex);
                }

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    result.HandleError(ex, content);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
```

And here is the exception being thrown:

`System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckDeferredCallDone(ConnectStream stream)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`

I've googled around and most answers seem to revolve around this error: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312629

What might be the cause of the error and how should I avoid or handle it?

Comment: I have a similar issue, but with SharePoint CSOM code which is calling those methods internally. Looks like at some point IIS server decides to end a thread where code is running for some reason. Memory issue, performance? Random recycle because of too many threads running for some unknown error in the code which is not disposing something? Maybe something else? I am not sure. While I don't have direct access to the IIS I'll have to check with administrators there to take a look into the logs.